# How do I fix SwipeRefreshLayout jerkiness?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

The SwipeRefreshLayout was added to the Android Support Library in v19.1.0:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

I have now added it to my application and it works as advertised. However, if I swipe slowly, I notice the overscroll is very jerky. See this video to see what I mean:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAuadMZYRf0

I see the issue using multiple layouts of varying levels of complexity. The layout shown in the video linked above is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And the relevant Java code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);

    mSwipeRefreshWidget = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_widget);
    mSwipeRefreshWidget.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mSwipeRefreshWidget.setColorScheme(R.color.refresh1, R.color.refresh2, R.color.refresh3,
            R.color.refresh4);

    // snip
}
```

Full source on Github:
https://github.com/meisteg/PickTheWinner/blob/d764c69af0c72a2d1173c6fb4328bd85088d8b59/app/src/com/meiste/greg/ptw/tab/Schedule.java

Anyone have suggestions how to fix the jerkiness? The overscroll should be smooth, no matter how long I take to overscroll the required distance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the 20.0 version of the support-library v4.
If you are using gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0'
```